# SQLite Android 9

Tags: android, sqlite

Estou com problemas para trabalhar com meu aplicativo no Android 9. Em alguns aparelhos que eram Android 8 e fizeram o upgrade para o Android 9 funciona, mas nos aparelhos que vem com uma versão mais nova do Android 9 de fábrica ele não consegue trazer os dados. Já fiz o teste e o banco de dados está sendo copiado para a área de dados do aparelho, porém não traz as informações.
Vou postar o código que estou utilizando para que se possível alguém me ajude. Se tiver algum erro grotesco me perdoem, pois sou iniciante na linguagem.
Obs: Nas versões anteriores a 9 funciona perfeitamente.

Desde já muito  obrigado.

public class RepositorioConfiguracao {

```
private static final String NOME_BANCO = "MB_DADOS";

protected SQLiteDatabase db;

public class MySQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    MySQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String databaseName) {
        super(context, databaseName, null, 2);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }
}


public RepositorioConfiguracao(Context ctx) {


    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        MySQLiteOpenHelper helper = new MySQLiteOpenHelper(ctx, NOME_BANCO);
        SQLiteDatabase database = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        String myPath = database.getPath();
        Log.i("Eficaz","Path = "+myPath);
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        db.disableWriteAheadLogging();

        } else {
            db = ctx.openOrCreateDatabase(NOME_BANCO, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        }

}



public DbConfiguracao BuscaConfig(int Empresa) {
    DbConfiguracao config = null;

    try {
```

Comment: tentou um logcat para ver se esta gerando algum erro ?

Comment: Minha aplicação foi criada com a API 19, sempre que testo no emulador ou em algum aparelho nessa versão não da erro algum. Não consegui rodar em um emulador ou aparelho com a API28 pois ele da uma mensagem de dispositivo não é compatível.